# Yii2 лишние стили, как их убрать?

Tags: css, yii2

Yii2 advanced из коробки.
Что это и почему это прописывается методом head()? 
Bootstrap css и js отключил через assetManager. Как отключить вот эту ерунду?

[image: csrfMetaTags]

Comment: такого css с коробки нет, от куда в вы его клонировали ?

Comment: @madfan41k С официального сайта. Специально посмотрел на других проектах и открыл первый случайный сайт на yii2 из гугла, там тоже самое есть. Вот: http://f3pro.ru/site/login или вот http://lowbase.ru Откройте в инспекторе и убедитесь сами. Не то, чтобы оно мне мешает. Просто мой внутренний перфекционист негодует и не понимает что это за странные стили. Один пустой css блок, а другой с кучей стилей с ссылками на левые сайты.

Comment: Хм...попробовал в мозиле, там нет такого. Выходит только опера добавляет стили, но только в проектах yii2...ничего не понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные стили добавляет расширение в браузере (Adblock или подобное), пряча таким образом рекламу на ресурсе.